# Firebase Realtime rules using auth.token.phoneNumber

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am having a problem writing Security Rules for my Firebase Realtime database, I have read the documentation but it was not really helpful in my case. As you can see below that the number stored in the database doesn't contain the country code

**Realtime database Structure:**

[image: Firebase Security Rules]

but the number that I am getting in firebase rules from auth.token.phonenNumber contains the country code. So, as you can see in the rules below, I have replaced the country code with "0" to check if it exists or not. But the problem is that I'm replacing the country code for only one country which is hard coded. I want it to be more generic, so I can replace all the country codes. If there is any way this is possible please let me know. And also I cannot change the database structure now.

**Firebase Security Rules:**
[image: Firebase Security Rules]

**Numbers Stored in Firebase phone number Authentication:**

[image]

***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: Why don't you save those phone numbers in the Realtime Database using the country code in the first place?

Comment: yes, you are right but it is what it is, I cannot change it now due to many reasons.

Comment: @AlexMamo can you suggest any other rule that I can use in this situation rather than checking if the number exists ?

Comment: Have you considered using regex on `.replace()`?

Comment: Have you tried Robert's suggestion?

Comment: @RobertG No I haven't but I know that the matches method accepts a regex, Can you please explain how can I use this here?